# Syncing Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2015, dropbox

I have a Visual Studio project that I want to work on in two computers.

I'm looking for how to sync the project between the computers.

I have a few options, and I'm open to other suggestions:

1. Dropbox
2. OneDrive, which is integrated nicely in Windows 10.
3. Github, although I'm not sure if it is used for this purpose, and don't want my code to be public.

What has worked for you?

Thanks!

Comment: Using a VCS is much less error-prone than Dropbox or OneDrive.  If you don't want your code to be public, try BitBucket.

Comment: Sorry, but what is VCS? Do you have any opinions on GitHub vs BitBucket?

Comment: VCS = Version Control System.  I use BitBucket because you can have unlimited private repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Visual Studio, then [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs) is good for you.

For source control you can use TFVC or Git and it's free (for team up to 5 people) and repositories are private.

Comment: I have used this and can verify it works great with Visual Studio 2015 Community and Professional.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub is a nice choice, not only to share between machines, but mainly as version control.

Also, if your version of Visual Studio supports it, you could use [TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/tfs-overview-vs.aspx) - the versioning integrated to it.

OneDrive or Dropbox doesn't have version control - once your project grows, you will notice it is really needed.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Do you have any opinions on GitHub vs BitBucket?

Comment: I've never user BitBucket. GitHub is pretty nice, reliable, easy to learn - Here is a doc that could help you: https://training.github.com/kit/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

For source control I would prefer tortoise svn (over git and bitbucket) - because it's easier to use.

For data replication / sync - google drive. Its similar to microsoft one drive, but bit faster.

Oh common - downvoters ! :-) I know you're absolutely love git, but unfortunately it's too over abstract, lacks of proper error handling, to difficult to use.
We can skype if you think otherwise, and I can prove it to you.

Comment: Maybe it was because you didn't mention VSTS. ;)

Comment: need to try it out before buying it. All new fancy technologies looks normally bit odd to me. Why to make it more complex than it already is ?